# Firestore returning no records yet, I see them in console

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

from my app and javascript console

```
firestore.collection('organizations/f1f4002a-1fb2-4805-baf1-a1a709f228e9/emailsSent').get().then(console.log)
```

returns QuerySnapshot with empty: true

yet there IS clearly one record. 
Every other query I write seems to work. ie assignmentLogs, emails, etc.

```

[image: firebase console]

I feel like I'm going crazy and it's probably something really stupid so I apologize in advance.

Comment: only difference I can see is that I generated the ids myself using uuid-v4 instead of having firestore generate them. Seems to be fine in the firebase console however

Comment: You may not have permission to access the data. To know this, add a `.catch(console.error)` at the end. So `.get().then(console.log).catch(console.error)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that the document name `455...2c2` is shown in *italics* in the console, which definitely not the normal case for documents displayed in the console.  That italics actually means that the document was deleted, however, it probably contains other subcollections that were not deleted (try clicking into it).

Since Firestore queries are shallow, the get() you're trying to perform is not going to yield any documents, because there are not actually any documents in that collection.

Something in your system may have deleted that document and not deleted its subcollections, so it's probably worthwhile to figure out what's responsible for that delete, and modify it so that it deletes its subcollections as well (otherwise they will remain "orphaned" in your database like this indefinitely).

Meanwhere, there's nothing much you can do about your query as shown - it's returning the correct results.

Comment: I did notice that after. No records were deleted, they never existed at that spot, only deeper nested. I was trying to get the list of ids for that level but apparently you can't so I added a key of something: true or whatever, and then you can query them.

Thank you, this is basically the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
const db = admin.firestore();

return db.collection('organizations/f1f4002a-1fb2-4805-baf1-a1a709f228e9/emailsSent').get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach (doc => {
    console.log(`ID: ${doc.id}`);
    console.log(doc.data());
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work since there are no docs. Empty is true. This was, of course, my original code.
Using the REST API for this URL also returns an empty {}
without a "documents" key

Comment: I created the same document structure and ran this code.  It returned the one document in `emailsSent`

Comment: Ok, I know what I'm doing wrong. The data is in fact, empty. There is no data at that point. I am trying to get data that is nested deeper inside. 

So "organizations/f1f4002a-1fb2-4805-baf1-a1a709f228e9/emailsSent/455 .../.." works

My apologizes and thanks for your help.